# upgraded from django 1.1 to 2.2, - (error) post_detail_view() got an unexpected keyword argument 'day'

Tags: python, django

(models.py)
    from django.utils import timezone

```
class Post(models.Model):

publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse ('post_detail',args= 
    [self.publish.year,self.publish.strftime('%m'),self.publish.strftime('%d'),self.slug])
```

views.py

```
def post_detail_view(request,year,month,post):

 post=get_object_or_404(Post,slug=post,status='published',publish__year='year',publish__month='month',publish__day='day')
    return render(request,'blog/post_detail.html',{'post':post})
```

** gives error as -- post_detail_view() got an unexpected keyword argument 'day'

please help

url.py

```
re_path('(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$',views.post_detail_view,name='post_detail')
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you don't have `day` in `def post_detail_view(request,year,month,post):` - but you have `day` in `re_path('(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/`. Maybe simply add `day` in `def post_detail_view(request,year,month, **day**, post):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wil guess.

You have `day` ( `(?P<day>\d{2})` ) in

```
re_path('(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/...', views.post_detail_view, ...)
```

so it may get url with `day` and send this `day` as argument to `post_detail_view`

but you don't have `day` in

```
def post_detail_view(request,year,month,post):
```

so it has problem what to do with this `day`.

Maybe simply add `day`

```
def post_detail_view(request,year,month,  day,  post):
```

Comment: after adding 'day' to the views function, it gives another error  invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'day'

Comment: after adding 'day' to the views function, it gives another error [ invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'day', ]   I tried to put 
def post_detail_view(request,year,month,day,post):
    post=get_object_or_404(Post,slug=post,status='published',publish__year=int('year'),publish__month=int('month'),publish__day=int('day'))
    return render(request,'blog/post_detail.html',{'post':post})

Comment: in `get_object_or_404(day)` you have to use variables `day`, `month`, `year`, not strings `'day'`, `'month'`, `'year'`. Now you use string `"day"` so it try to do `int("day")` but you need `int(day)`, `int(month)`, `int(year)`